# Inheriting CSS Width

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Hello. My problem is that I would like `.mylargeframe` to strecth across the entire width of the browser.

CSS

```
.mylargeframe {
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f8f8f8);
  border: 1px solid #d0d2d5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bebfc2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
}

fieldset {
  background:#ebeced;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #d0d2d5;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  margin: 5px 0 -20px -20px;  padding: 18px 20px;
  width: auto;
}

fieldset input {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <div class="mylargeframe">
   <fieldset>
     test
   </fieldset>
  </div>
</html>
```

The problem is that it is not completely filled, but it is almost there. I am using Firefox and Chrome

Comment: You have `width: 80%` on `.mylargeframe`.  Why would you expect it to go the whole way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `width: auto;` in `fieldset` with `100%`.

```
fieldset
{
    background:#ebeced;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #d0d2d5;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    margin: 5px 0 -20px -20px;  padding: 18px 20px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Now, the `fieldset` will take up the `width` of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

This way the fieldset will fill your div ;)

```
fieldset
{ 
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

You'll need the box sizing, otherwise the width will be 100% + margins